# How do I join multiple texts together on selenium?

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I got this below error. I know that i have to join the Strings together but i don't know how.

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, WebElement found

```
import random
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/Guest/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Guest/Desktop/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)

copy = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[contains(@class,'ui_qtext_para u-ltr u-text-align--start')]")
for text in copy:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@placeholder='']/div").send_keys(copy)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your code as shown below.

```
 for text in copy:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@placeholder='Traducir la respuesta']/div").send_keys(text.text)
```

Comment: I assume 'copy' is an array of elements here. You cannot add '.text'

Comment: Edited my answer. Thanks for noticing that. Not much aware of selenium with python. Usually Java is my programming language.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I might mixing things. If ```copy``` is an array/list - how can you call ```.text``` method?
I am just saying, e.g. copy=[obj1, obj2, obj3] - then how can you apply copy.text? What will be the output then